# Zend Framework not handing camel case controller properly in unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, zend-framework

I'm working on my first ZF project and am a bit stuck. I have a controller named 'WebServiceController' and I have a unit test for the WebServiceController but when I run the test it doesn't assert the controller properly. My test code is:

```
public function testIndexAction() {
        $params = array('action' => 'index', 'controller' => 'WebService', 'module' => 'default');
        $url = $this->url($this->urlizeOptions($params));
        $this->dispatch($url);

        // assertions
        $this->assertModule($params['module']);
        $this->assertController($params['controller']);
        $this->assertAction($params['action']);
        $this->assertQueryContentContains(
            'div#view-content p',
            'View script for controller <b>' . $params['controller'] . '</b> and script/action name <b>' . $params['action'] . '</b>'
            );
    }
```

The error I get is:

1) WebServiceControllerTest::testIndexAction
Failed asserting last controller used <"Web-Service"> was "WebService"

It looks like its trying to assert the controller was 'Web-Service' instead of 'WebService'. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Ziad

p.s. I am using ZF 1.11.5

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Zend Framework a camel case name for controller is rewritten in the URL :

`WebService` in the class name becomes `web-service` in the URL.

This is a normal behavior, see http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.basics.html :

> Since humans are notoriously
>   inconsistent at maintaining case
>   sensitivity when typing links, Zend
>   Framework actually normalizes path
>   information to lowercase. This, of
>   course, will affect how you name your
>   controller and actions... or refer to
>   them in links. If you wish to have
>   your controller class or action method
>   name have multiple MixedCasedWords or
>   camelCasedWords, you will need to
>   separate those words on the url with
>   either a '-' or '.' (though you can
>   configure the character used). As an
>   example, if you were going to the
>   action in
>   FooBarController::bazBatAction(),
>   you'd refer to it on the url as
>   /foo-bar/baz-bat or /foo.bar/baz.bat.

Comment: Thanks for your response Matthieu, I changed $params to have 'web-service' as the controller and that fixed the camel casing and I had to change the output that was expected as well because the view contains 'WebService' hardcoded.